# How to change a dataframe column from String type to Double type in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with column as String.
I wanted to change the column type to Double type in PySpark.

Following is the way, I did:

```
toDoublefunc = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: x,DoubleType())
changedTypedf = joindf.withColumn("label",toDoublefunc(joindf['show']))
```

Just wanted to know, is this the right way to do it as while running
through Logistic Regression, I am getting some error, so I wonder,
is this the reason for the trouble.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

There is no need for an UDF here. `Column` already provides [`cast` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.cast) with [`DataType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=datatype#pyspark.sql.types.DataType) *instance* :

```python
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

changedTypedf = joindf.withColumn("label", joindf["show"].cast(DoubleType()))
```

or short string:

```python
changedTypedf = joindf.withColumn("label", joindf["show"].cast("double"))
```

where canonical string names (other variations can be supported as well) correspond to `simpleString` value. So for atomic types:

```
from pyspark.sql import types 

for t in ['BinaryType', 'BooleanType', 'ByteType', 'DateType', 
          'DecimalType', 'DoubleType', 'FloatType', 'IntegerType', 
           'LongType', 'ShortType', 'StringType', 'TimestampType']:
    print(f"{t}: {getattr(types, t)().simpleString()}")
```

```
BinaryType: binary
BooleanType: boolean
ByteType: tinyint
DateType: date
DecimalType: decimal(10,0)
DoubleType: double
FloatType: float
IntegerType: int
LongType: bigint
ShortType: smallint
StringType: string
TimestampType: timestamp
```

and for example complex types

```py
types.ArrayType(types.IntegerType()).simpleString()
```

```
'array<int>'
```

```py
types.MapType(types.StringType(), types.IntegerType()).simpleString()
```

```
'map<string,int>'
```

Comment: Using the `col` function also works.
`from pyspark.sql.functions import col`,  


`changedTypedf = joindf.withColumn("label", col("show").cast(DoubleType()))
`

Comment: What are the possible values of cast() argument (the "string" syntax)?

Comment: I can't believe how terse Spark doc was on the valid string for the datatype. The closest reference I could find was this: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-analyst/7.7.1/doc/html/en-US/TIB_sfire-analyst_UsersGuide/connectors/apache-spark/apache_spark_data_types.htm .

Comment: How to convert multiple columns in one go?

Comment: How do I change nullable to false?

Answer (score 81):

Preserve the name of the column and avoid extra column addition by using the same name as input column:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
changedTypedf = joindf.withColumn("show", joindf["show"].cast(DoubleType()))
```

Comment: Thanks I was looking for how to retain original column name

Comment: is there a list somewhere of the short string data types Spark will identify?

Comment: this solution also works splendidly in a loop e.g. `from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
for ftr in ftr_list:
    df = df.withColumn(f, df[f].cast(IntegerType()))`

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl Your code is wrong. What is `f`? Where are you using `ftr`?

Comment: Yeh, thanks -- 'f' should be 'ftr'. Others likely figured that out.

Answer (score 16):

Given answers are enough to deal with the problem but I want to share another way which may be introduced the new version of Spark *(I am not sure about it)* so given answer didn't catch it.

We can reach the column in spark statement with `col("colum_name")` keyword:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
changedTypedf = joindf.withColumn("show", col("show").cast("double"))
```

Comment: Thank you! Using `'double'` is more elegant than `DoubleType()` which may also need to be imported.

Answer (score 7):

PySpark version:

```
df = <source data>
df.printSchema()

from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Change column type
df_new = df.withColumn("myColumn", df["myColumn"].cast(IntegerType()))
df_new.printSchema()
df_new.select("myColumn").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution was simple -

```
toDoublefunc = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: float(x),DoubleType())
changedTypedf = joindf.withColumn("label",toDoublefunc(joindf['show']))
```

Answer (score 1):

use：

```
df1.select(col('show').cast("Float").alias('label')).show()
```

or

```
df1.selectExpr("cast(show AS FLOAT) as label").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue with other answers (depending on your version of Pyspark) is usage of `withColumn`. Performance issues have been observed at least in v2.4.4 (see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59789689/spark-dag-differs-with-withcolumn-vs-select)). The [spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#withColumn(colName:String,col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) mention this about `withColumn`:

> this method introduces a projection internally. Therefore, calling it multiple times, for instance, via loops in order to add multiple columns can generate big plans which can cause performance issues and even StackOverflowException. To avoid this, use select with the multiple columns at once.

One way to achieve the recommended usage of `select` instead in general would be:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols_to_fix = ['show']
other_cols = [col for col in joindf.columns if not col in cols_to_fix]
joindf = joindf.select(
    *other_cols,
    F.col('show').cast(DoubleType())
)
```