# Cast a very long string as an integer or Long Integer in PySpark

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working with a string column which is 38 characters long and is actually numerical.

for e.g. id = '678868938393937838947477478778877.....' ( 38 characters long).

How do I cast it into a long integer ? I have tried cast function with IntegerType, LongType and DoubleType and when i try to show the column it yields Nulls.

The reason I want to do this is because I need to do some inner joins using this column and doing it as String is giving me Java Heap Space Errors.

Any suggestions on how to cast it as a Long Integer ? { This question tries to cast a string into a Long Integer }

Comment: I can't reproduce, using python 2.7, I just do int(id) and have no problem

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change a Dataframe column from String type to Double type in pyspark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284620/how-to-change-a-dataframe-column-from-string-type-to-double-type-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short you simply don't. Spark `DataFrame` is a JVM object which uses following types mapping:

- `IntegerType` -> `Integer` with `MAX_VALUE` equal  2 ** 31 - 1
- `LongType` -> `Long` with `MaxValue` equal 2 ** 63 - 1

You could try to use `DecimalType` with maximum allowed precission (38).

```
df = sc.parallelize([("9" * 38, "9" * 39)]).toDF(["x", "y"])
df.select(col("x").cast("decimal(38, 0)")).show(1, False)

## +--------------------------------------+
## |x                                     |
## +--------------------------------------+
## |99999999999999999999999999999999999999|
## +---------------------------------------
```

With larger numbers you can cast to double but not without a loss of precision:

```
df.select(
    col("y").cast("decimal(38, 0)"), col("y").cast("double")).show(1, False)

## +----+------+
## |y   |y     |
## +----+------+
## |null|1.0E39|
## +----+------+
```

That being said casting to numeric types won't help you with memory errors.

Comment: The method works for me.  @zero323 , I'll look at your last suggestion that casting to numeric types won't help with memory errors.

Comment: @zero323 - Little late to the part but i disagree, can you elaborate why casting will not help with memory errors? String will inherently consume more memory, and will consume more heap