# SparklyR: Convert directly to parquet

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

Hi I am new to cluster computing and currently I am only playing around on the standalone cluster (`sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = '2.0.2')`). I have a massive csv file (15GB) which I would like to convert to a parquet file (Third chunk of code explains why). This 15GB file is already a sample of a 60GB file, and I need to use/query the full 60GB file when I stop playing arround.  Currently what I did was:

```
> system.time({FILE<-spark_read_csv(sc,"FILE",file.path("DATA/FILE.csv"),memory = FALSE)})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.16    0.04 1017.11 
> system.time({spark_write_parquet(FILE, file.path("DATA/FILE.parquet"),mode='overwrite')})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.92    1.48 1267.72 
> system.time({FILE<-spark_read_parquet(sc,"FILE", file.path("DATA/FILE.parquet"),memory = FALSE)})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.00    0.00    0.26
```

As you can see this takes quite a long time. I was wondering what happens in the first line of code (`spark_read_csv`) with `memory = FALSE` ? Where does it read/save it to? and can I access that location when I disconnect and reconnect the session again?

Also, is there a way to combine step 1 & 2 in a more efficient way?

I am not shy to try and use lower level functions that aren't available in the API yet given that it is simple and can be automated to a large degree.

Comment: @Noobie unfortunately not.. I think by setting up a Hive database and not using `master = "local"` will solve the problem, but haven't tried it yet. If you find out anything please post to this feed please for everyone's gain.

Comment: How wide is you data, i.e. do you have many variables and do you need to work with all of them? The `memory=FALSE` flag tells Spark **not** to load the complete DataFrame into memory... this is useful in particular if you're interested in just a bunch of columns. For example, if you run something like `FILE %>% select(var1, var2) %>% filter(var2 > 1) %>% compute()`, Spark will load only the selected and filtered columns into memory and not the whole dataframe. This speeds up processing massively.

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ The delay is related to schema inference and no data is saved. If you want to avoid it, you should provide schema explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

No data is saved when `spark_read_csv` is invoked with `memory = FALSE`. The delay you is related not to data loading as such, but to schema inference process, which requires a separate data scan.

As convenient as it is to use schema inference, it is much better performance-wise to provide schema explicitly, as named vector, mapping from column names to [to type's simple string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32286450). For example if you were to load iris dataset in a `local` mode:

```
path <- tempfile()
readr::write_csv(iris, path)
```

you'd use

```
spark_read_csv(
  sc, "iris", path, infer_schema=FALSE, memory = FALSE,
  columns = c(
    Sepal_Length = "double", Sepal_Width = "double", 
    Petal_Length = "double", Petal_Width = "double",
    Species = "string"))
```

Comment: we miss you here :'(