# Can't load .csv data in a local Spark connection when using sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

**Background**: I am completely new to the whole Spark platform & concept and I am trying to learn how to operate it with via `R` with `sparklyr`. I started following an online course on the topic and I am trying to use it for my own data analysis as a way to learn it.

**Problem**: I am trying to load a 6.3gb csv dataset (~30 mil rows, ~20 cols) but I get the following error (from what I could tell, the same chunks kept repeating themselves, I give here the first 3 of them, as I will otherwise reach the character limit for the post). The code runs but after 17 minutes it exits with the following error (no data is loaded):

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:139)
sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:139)
sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$parallelize$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:716)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$parallelize$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:715)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.parallelize(SparkContext.scala:715)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:139)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:
```

Here is my R code:

```
library(sparklyr)
spark_install(version = "2.1.0")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
testdata = spark_read_csv(sc, name = "testdata", path = ...)
```

Outside of Spark, I am able to load the file e.g. using `read_csv`. I googled the issue and it has been mentioned that potential cause is an OutOfMemory issue - I am not quite sure if this is the problem and how to fix it.

I'd be grateful if someone could point me out a way how to debug it and fix it!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- Unless you use tiny data you should forget about `local` mode. It is primarily designed for testing and small scale experimentation, not for working on even moderate size data.

  As it uses only a single JVM for both driver and executor code, the potential for serious fault recovery, and if processing goes AWOL you might loose a whole session (which seems to be the case here).

  So if you want to test things locally on a moderate size data consider using [standalone mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) otherwise just downscale the dataset.

  On a side note `local` mode uses only one processing thread. Even for testing it makes more sense to use `local[n]` (for `n` threads) or `local[*]` (for all available cores).
- Be ready to adjust the configuration as default values are extremely conservative - for example `spark.driver.memory` is by default 1 GB - you might get away with it, in a standalone mode, but not when all components are embedded in a single JVM.
- Don't trust sparklyr defaults.

  sparklyr developers made a very unfortunate choice of eagerly caching data in memory by default. It not only goes against Spark defaults (which, [for a reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52130402), uses `MEMORY_AND_DISK` for `Dataset` API) and rarely provides any practical benefits on real size data, but also interferes with Spark optimizer in some ugly ways (most notably preventing projection and selection pushdown).

  So get into a habit of using `memory = FALSE` whenever applicable:

  ```
  spark_read_csv(sc, name = "testdata", memory = FALSE, path = ...)
  ```
- Provide schema for the reader instead of using schema inference. See [SparklyR: Convert directly to parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44624093/6910411)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful!  I see that I have to invest a lot more time into understanding this - if you would have a suggestion for an easy to understand guide or other sources, kindly let me know.

Another question: what is actualy considered tiny data when it comes to what you describe about using "local"? Is my 30mil rows/12 columns considered small/moderate or big in this context?
Cheers

Comment: My personal path of choice would be to learn core (i.e. Scala API, O'Reilly has a bunch of decent books, by Spark contributors, EPFL has nice MOOC on Coursera)  and then move to sparklyr, but I realize that might not be the most appealing path. Other than that, just don't get deceived by a familiar API - it is your worst enemy here. As of moderate it is subjective and fuzzy, however you can try to compare things to the available memory - if size of the raw data is of the same order of magnitude as the available RAM I'd call it "moderate". For learning I'd use at least order of magnitude less.