# How do I add a column to a nested struct in a PySpark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a schema like

```
root
 |-- state: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fld: integer (nullable = true)
```

I'd like to add columns within the `state` struct, that is, create a dataframe with a schema like

```
root
 |-- state: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fld: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
```

I tried

```py
df.withColumn('state.a', val).printSchema()
# root
#  |-- state: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- fld: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- state.a: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: You can create a new column using a udf with the schema you desire and drop the old one. As far as I know, you can't change the schema of struct column. [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824403/pyspark-change-nested-column-datatype/45841615#45841615)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is a way to do it without using a `udf`:

```python
# create example dataframe
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
data = [
    ({'fld': 0},)
]

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('state',
            StructType(
                [StructField('fld', IntegerType())]
            )
        )
    ]
)

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- state: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- fld: integer (nullable = true)
```

Now use `withColumn()` and add the new field using `lit()` and `alias()`.

```python
val = 1
df_new = df.withColumn(
    'state', 
    f.struct(*[f.col('state')['fld'].alias('fld'), f.lit(val).alias('a')])
)
df_new.printSchema()
#root
# |-- state: struct (nullable = false)
# |    |-- fld: integer (nullable = true)
# |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
```

If you have a lot of fields in the nested struct you can use a list comprehension, using `df.schema["state"].dataType.names` to get the field names. For example:

```python
val = 1
s_fields = df.schema["state"].dataType.names # ['fld']
df_new = df.withColumn(
    'state', 
    f.struct(*([f.col('state')[c].alias(c) for c in s_fields] + [f.lit(val).alias('a')]))
)
df_new.printSchema()
#root
# |-- state: struct (nullable = false)
# |    |-- fld: integer (nullable = true)
# |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
```

**References**

- I found a way to get the field names from the Struct without naming them manually from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48448731/5858851).

Comment: I see, use `withColumn` to replace the `struct` with a new struct, so copy over the old fields. This works, thanks! I wonder if there is a way to add field to the struct, without having to name all the existing sub fields?

Comment: @MrCartoonology I found a cleaner way to get the field names. See the update.

Answer (score 24):

Use a transformation such as the following:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = df.withColumn(
    "state",
    f.struct(
        f.col("state.*"),
        f.lit(123).alias("a")
    )
)
```

Comment: AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(state)`;

Comment: @BlueClouds what's your dataframe schema (specifically, what's the column type for `state` in this case) – ?

Comment: state is a struct

Comment: are you sure about that because you're getting an error message that suggests it's not a struct data type – what happens if you print the schema?

Answer (score 5):

Although this is a too late answer, for pyspark version 2.x.x following is supported.

Assuming `dfOld` already contains `state` and `fld` as asked in question.

`dfOld.withColumn("a","value")
dfNew = dfOld.select("level1Field1", "level1Field2", struct(col("state.fld").alias("fld"), col("a")).alias("state"))`

Reference: https://medium.com/@mrpowers/adding-structtype-columns-to-spark-dataframes-b44125409803

Answer (score 5):

**Spark 3.1+**

```py
F.col('state').withField('a', F.lit(1))
```

---

Example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([((1,),)], 'state:struct<fld:int>')
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- state: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- fld: integer (nullable = true)

df = df.withColumn('state', F.col('state').withField('a', F.lit(1)))
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- state: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- fld: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: One reason of getting `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable` is using a Spark version lower than 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it ***without*** a udf.

**Initialize example dataframe:**

```
nested_df1 = (spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(["""[
        { "state": {"fld": 1} },
        { "state": {"fld": 2}}
    ]"""])))

nested_df1.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- state: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fld: long (nullable = true)
```

Spark `.read.json` imports all integers as `long` by default.
If `state.fld` has to be an `int`, you will need to cast it.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

nested_df1 = (nested_df1
    .select( F.struct(F.col("state.fld").alias("fld").cast('int')).alias("state") ))

nested_df1.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- state: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- col1: integer (nullable = true)
```

```
nested_df1.show()
```

```
+-----+
|state|
+-----+
|  [1]|
|  [2]|
+-----+
```

#### Finally

Use `.select` to get the nested columns you want from the existing struct with the `"parent.child"` notation, create the new column, then re-wrap the old columns together with the new columns in a `struct`.

```
val_a = 3

nested_df2 = (nested_df
    .select( 
        F.struct(
            F.col("state.fld"), 
            F.lit(val_a).alias("a")
        ).alias("state")
    )
)


nested_df2.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- state: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- fld: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
```

```
nested_df2.show()
```

```
+------+
| state|
+------+
|[1, 3]|
|[2, 3]|
+------+
```

Flatten if needed with `"parent.*"`.

```
nested_df2.select("state.*").printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- fld: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
```

```
nested_df2.select("state.*").show()
```

```
+---+---+
|fld|  a|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
|  2|  3|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `struct` function

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = df.withColumn(
    "state",
    f.struct(
        f.col("state.fld").alias("fld"),
        f.lit(1).alias("a")
    )
)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
def add_field_in_dataframe(nfield, df, dt): 
    fields = nfield.split(".")
    print fields
    n = len(fields)
    addField = fields[0]  
    if n == 1:
        return df.withColumn(addField, lit(None).cast(dt))

    nestedField = ".".join(fields[:-1])
    sfields = df.select(nestedField).schema[fields[-2]].dataType.names
    print sfields
    ac = col(nestedField)
    if n == 2:
        nc = struct(*( [ac[c].alias(c) for c in sfields] + [lit(None).cast(dt).alias(fields[-1])]))
    else:
        nc = struct(*( [ac[c].alias(c) for c in sfields] + [lit(None).cast(dt).alias(fields[-1])])).alias(fields[-2])
    print nc
    n = n - 1

    while n > 1: 
        print "n: ",n
        fields = fields[:-1]
        print "fields: ", fields
        nestedField = ".".join(fields[:-1])
        print "nestedField: ", nestedField
        sfields = df.select(nestedField).schema[fields[-2]].dataType.names
        print fields[-1]
        print "sfields: ", sfields
        sfields = [s for s in sfields if s != fields[-1]]
        print "sfields: ", sfields
        ac = col(".".join(fields[:-1]))
        if n > 2: 
            print fields[-2]
            nc = struct(*( [ac[c].alias(c) for c in sfields] + [nc])).alias(fields[-2])
        else:
            nc = struct(*( [ac[c].alias(c) for c in sfields] + [nc]))
        n = n - 1
    return df.withColumn(addField, nc)
```