# Add a column to a struct nested in an array

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame with an array of structs, containing two columns (`colorcode` and `name`). I want to add a new column to the struct, `newcol`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777993/how-do-i-add-a-column-to-a-nested-struct-in-a-pyspark-dataframe) answered "how to add a column to a nested struct", but I'm failing to transfer it to my case, where the struct is further nested inside an array. I can't seem to reference/recreate the array-struct schema.

My schema:

```
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Dep: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ABC: string (nullable = true)
```

What is should become:

```
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Dep: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ABC: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- newcol: string (nullable = true)
```

How do I transfer the solution to my nested struct?

Reproducible code to get a df of the above schema:

```
data = [
    (10, [{"Dep": 10, "ABC": 1}, {"Dep": 10, "ABC": 1}]),
    (20, [{"Dep": 20, "ABC": 1}, {"Dep": 20, "ABC": 1}]),
    (30, [{"Dep": 30, "ABC": 1}, {"Dep": 30, "ABC": 1}]),
    (40, [{"Dep": 40, "ABC": 1}, {"Dep": 40, "ABC": 1}])
  ]
myschema = StructType(
[
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("values",
                ArrayType(
                    StructType([
                        StructField("Dep", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("ABC", StringType(), True)
                    ])
    ))
]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=myschema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(10, False)
```

Comment: Please add some reproducible code

Comment: what is your spark version?

Comment: pyspark 3.2.1, I am working on a reproducible code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For spark version >= 3.1, you can use the `transform` function and `withField` method to achieve this.

`transform` performs the transformation calculation according to the provided function for each element (struct(Dep, ABC) here) in the `array` (`values` column here). `withField` adds/replaces a field in StructType by name.

```
df = df.withColumn('values', F.transform('values', lambda x: x.withField('newcol', F.lit(1))))
```

Comment: try: ```df = df.withColumn('values', F.transform('values', lambda x: x.withField('Dep', x['Dep'].cast('int'))))```

Comment: This  looks neater `df.withColumn("values",F.expr("transform(values, x -> struct(cast((x.Dep) as integer) as Dep, x.ABC))"))`

Comment: It depends on personal habits and familiarity. At the beginning, I was used to answering questions using spark sql expressions, but I found that many people are more used to the dataframe API.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, of doing it would be using sql expressions.

```
df = df.withColumn("values",F.expr("transform(values, x -> struct(COALESCE('1') as newcol,x.Dep,x.ABC))"))
```