# update nested struct with null values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a column which is nested StructType. The StructType is deeply nested and may comprise other Structs. Now I want to update this column at the lowest level.
I tried withField but it doesn't work if any of the top level struct is null. I will appreciate any help with this.

The example schema is:

```
val schema = new StructType()
      .add("key", StringType)
      .add(
        "cells",
        ArrayType(
          new StructType()
            .add("family", StringType)
            .add("qualifier", StringType)
            .add("timestamp", LongType)
            .add("nestStruct", new StructType()
                .add("id1", LongType)
                .add("id2", StringType)
.               .add("id3", new StructType()
                   .add("id31", LongType)
                   .add("id32", StringType))
        )
      )

val data = Seq(
      Row(
        "1235321863",
        Array(
          Row("a", "b", 1L,  null)
        )
      )
    )

  
   val  df_test = spark
      .createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema) 

val result = df_test.withColumn(
  "cell1",
  transform($"cells", cell => {
      cell.withField("nestStruct.id3.id31", lit(40)) /*This line doesn't do anything is nestStruct is null. */
  }))
result.show(false)
result.printSchema 
result.explain() /*The physical plan shows that if a field is null it will just return null*/
```

Comment: Can you add expected and actual output? If the parent struct is non-null, does it works as expected? Also, what do you expect if the parent is null?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution suggested for this question: [How do I add a column to a nested struct in a PySpark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777993/how-do-i-add-a-column-to-a-nested-struct-in-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Or you can try the following:
You can write your current dataframe to a json file, read the json file to a string, and try writing a regular expression to add the field you want to the json string, then write the json string to a new file, and read the new file to a dataframe.

For example, I'm using the example provided above:

```
import json, re

with open('./pyspark_sandbox_sample.json') as input_file:
    string_data = str(json.load(input_file))
input_file.close()

string_data = re.sub(r"'id32': '(.*?)'", r"'id32': '\1', 'id33': 40", string_data)

with open('./pyspark_sandbox_sample.json', 'w') as output_file:
    json.dump(eval(string_data), output_file)
output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The "struct" expression can be used to construct a struct column (similar to [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#struct-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-)).

Reproducing the example given in the question: -

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes.StringType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes.StringType

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{LongType, ArrayType, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{LongType, ArrayType, StructType}

scala> val schema = new StructType().add("key", StringType).add("cells",ArrayType(new StructType().add("family", StringType).add("qualifier", StringType).add("timestamp", LongType).add("nestStruct", new StructType().add("id1", LongType).add("id2", StringType).add("id3", new StructType().add("id31", LongType).add("id32", StringType)))))
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(key,StringType,true),StructField(cells,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(family,StringType,true),StructField(qualifier,StringType,true),StructField(timestamp,LongType,true),StructField(nestStruct,StructType(StructField(id1,LongType,true),StructField(id2,StringType,true),StructField(id3,StructType(StructField(id31,LongType,true),StructField(id32,StringType,true)),true)),true)),true),true))

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, functions}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, functions}

scala> val data = Seq(Row("d", Array(Row("a", "b", 1L,  null))))
data: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = List([d,[Lorg.apache.spark.sql.Row;@3cebe931])

scala> val df_test = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)
df_test: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, cells: array<struct<family:string,qualifier:string,timestamp:bigint,nestStruct:struct<id1:bigint,id2:string,id3:struct<id31:bigint,id32:string>>>>]

scala> val result = df_test.withColumn("cell1", functions.expr("transform(cells, cell -> struct(cell.family, cell.qualifier, cell.timestamp, struct(cell.nestStruct.id1, cell.nestStruct.id2, struct(40L as id31, cell.nestStruct.id3.id32) as id3) as nestStruct))"))
result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, cells: array<struct<family:string,qualifier:string,timestamp:bigint,nestStruct:struct<id1:bigint,id2:string,id3:struct<id31:bigint,id32:string>>>> ... 1 more field]

scala> result.show(truncate = false)
+---+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
|key|cells            |cell1                                |
+---+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
|d  |[{a, b, 1, NULL}]|[{a, b, 1, {NULL, NULL, {40, NULL}}}]|
+---+-----------------+-------------------------------------+

scala> result.withColumn("id32", functions.expr("transform(cell1, x -> x.nestStruct.id3.id31)")).show(truncate = false)
+---+-----------------+-------------------------------------+----+
|key|cells            |cell1                                |id32|
+---+-----------------+-------------------------------------+----+
|d  |[{a, b, 1, NULL}]|[{a, b, 1, {NULL, NULL, {40, NULL}}}]|[40]|
+---+-----------------+-------------------------------------+----+
```