# Pyspark struct array refer to previous element to find time difference and add a new column

Tags: pyspark

I have this schema

```
[(
'guid', 'string'),
(‘shop_time, 'array<struct<seconds:int,shop:string>>'),
]
```

and this data:

```
|006435a231e26c67df63340d1b3c2a5d4e|
[10, Texmex], [5, BurgerB]]
|006435asdsdsdsdderere340d1b3c2a5d4e|
[[20, Check], [10, Test]]
```

I would like this schema

```
[(
'guid', 'string'),
(‘shop_time, 'array<struct<seconds:int,shop:string,time_diff_sec:int>>'),
]
```

and this data as the result

```
|006435a231e26c67df63340d1b3c2a5d4e|
[10, Texmex,0], [5, BurgerB,5]]
|006435asdsdsdsdderere340d1b3c2a5d4e|
[[20, Check,0], [10, Test,10]]
```

So a new array column is added in struct named `time_diff_sec` and difference from previous column(upper) is calculated. First array col is 0/null because there is no previous element. I can do this using a window function in a normal dataframe. But how to do it in a struct array. Is there a window function for arrays? I know how to add a new column as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777993/how-do-i-add-a-column-to-a-nested-struct-in-a-pyspark-dataframe) , but how to refer to a previous column in an array?