# Spark assign a number for each word in collect

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an collect data of dataFrame column in spark

```
temp = df.select('item_code').collect()

Result: 

[Row(item_code=u'I0938'),
 Row(item_code=u'I0009'),
 Row(item_code=u'I0010'),
 Row(item_code=u'I0010'),
 Row(item_code=u'C0723'),
 Row(item_code=u'I1097'),
 Row(item_code=u'C0117'),
 Row(item_code=u'I0009'),
 Row(item_code=u'I0009'),
 Row(item_code=u'I0009'),
 Row(item_code=u'I0010'),
 Row(item_code=u'I0009'),
 Row(item_code=u'C0117'),
 Row(item_code=u'I0009'),
 Row(item_code=u'I0596')]
```

And now i would like assign a number for each word, if words is duplicate, it have the same number.
I using Spark, RDD , not Pandas

Please help me resolve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new dataframe which has distinct values.

```
val data = temp.distinct()
```

Now you can assigne a unique id using

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 

val dataWithId = data.withColumn("uniqueID",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
```

Now you can join this new dataframe with the original dataframe and select the unique id.

```
val tempWithId = temp.join(dataWithId, "item_code").select("item_code", "uniqueID")
```

The code is assuming scala. But something similar should exist for pyspark  as well. Just consider this as a pointer.

Comment: Now, can you help me assign a number have type is int (not bigInt)?

Comment: @PhongNguyen : Look at the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284620/how-to-change-a-dataframe-column-from-string-type-to-double-type-in-pyspark . You will have to cast the column to IntegerType