# Convert RDD[Row] containing strings To Dataframe Of IntegerTypes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, schema

I have the following RDD of Rows. As can be seen each field is a string type

```
[Row(A='6', B='1', C='hi'),
 Row(A='4', B='5', C='bye'),
 Row(A='8', B='9', C='night')]
```

I want to convert this RDD into a dataframe with IntegerTypes for column A and B

```
dtypes = [
    StructField('A', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('B', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('C', StringType(), True)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, StructType(dtypes))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: field A: IntegerType can not accept 
object '6' in type <class 'str'>
```

How can i succesfully convert '6' into an IntegerType?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46956026/how-to-convert-column-with-string-type-to-int-form-in-pyspark-data-frame

Comment: I saw that post. It is dealing directly with converting column types in a spark DF, not converting column types when creating dataframe from RDD

Comment: okay for that you need to modify your RDD of rows so that all those string data is casted to integer before you create the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the RDD of rows before you create a dataframe of desired column type.

```
def modify_row(row):
    new_row = {}
    for key in row:
        if key in ['A', 'B']:
             new_row[key] = int(row[key])
        else:
             new_row[key] = row[key]
    return new_row

rdd = (sc.parallelize([Row(A='6', B='1', C='hi'),
                      Row(A='4', B='5', C='bye'),
                      Row(A='8', B='9', C='night')])
         .map(lambda x: modify_row(x)))

dtypes = [
    StructField('A', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('B', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('C', StringType(), True)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, StructType(dtypes))
```

Comment: I like this solution. Was thinking the same. Kind of sucks that pyspark doesnt convert those columns to the desired type for you ... Will mark your solution as correct once I get this working. Thanks