# Do I need to create a new pyspark dataframe each time I perform a transformation?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm relatively new to PySpark. I understand that unlike pandas, PySpark dataframes are not mutable and does not allow tranformation in-place as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284620/how-to-change-a-dataframe-column-from-string-type-to-double-type-in-pyspark). So, I'm curious to know if can store the mutated dataframe as same  name of the old one like,

```
joindf = joindf.withColumn("label", joindf["show"].cast("double"))
```

I know that this operation is perfectly alright with other programming languages, overwriting the old value. Just want to confirm if it is same for PySpark too. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you can. And you can even use the same column name.