# How to get the average of a boolean column in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I tried using `.agg(avg("boolean_column"))`, but got the error:

```
"function average requires numeric types, not boolean"
```

How can I get the average of such a column?

Comment: Say you have two values: true, false. What's the average?

Comment: The avg of true and false implies the average of 1 and 0. i.e. 0.5

Comment: @ÓscarLópez For example: if you have a binary prediction problem where success is denoted by a boolean, we can take the average of this as an integer to calculate the "success rate"

Comment: Of course. but how in pyspark?

Generally, I think pyspark is so unintuitive

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but related to [how to change a Dataframe column from String type to Double type in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284620/how-to-change-a-dataframe-column-from-string-type-to-double-type-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the column to a numeric type, then take the average:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, col
df.groupBy(...).agg(avg(col("boolean_column").cast("double")))
```